# Removal of characters in AppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a "Sheet1" where column "B2:B" (excluding the header) has strings made up of letters (uppercase and lowercase ones), spaces, numbers and symbols.

My script has to take the strings in column "B2:B" and:

1. replace all uppercases into lowercases;
2. remove numbers, symbols (at the beginning, at the end, in the middle of the string);
3. replace spaces between words with dashes "-";
4. remove spaces at the beginning or end of the string.

After that, it puts the changed strings back into the right cells (overriding them).

For example, before any edit:

| ... | Header of column B | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | Apple1 | ... |
| ... | 1strong Bone | ... |
| ... | somEthing [double space] Written | ... |
| ... | [double space] hellOwor2ld | ... |
| ... | just?some ! Characters | ... |

After the edits:

| ... | Header of column B | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | apple | ... |
| ... | strong-bone | ... |
| ... | something-written | ... |
| ... | hello-world | ... |
| ... | just-some-characters | ... |

I've tried with a function from the sheet:

```
=SUBSTITUTE("B3", "1", "-")
```

but it couldn't search for multiple symbols at the same time.

I've also tried using:

```
var sheetId = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet-id");
var sheet = SS.getSheetByName("sheet-tab-id");
var range = sheet.getDataRange();

var remove = "1strong Bone";
var searchcolumn = 1; //because 0 is the first


function deleteRow(){  
  var valRange = range.getValues();

  for(var i = valRange.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(valRange[i][searchcolumn] === remove){
      
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
    };
  };
};
```

but it didn't improve my issue.

I'd appreciate any suggestion.

*Cross-posted over another forum: [excelforum.com/for-other-platforms-mac-google-docs-mobile-os-etc/1400484-remove-specific-characters-from-cells-with-appsscript-coding.html](https://excelforum.com/for-other-platforms-mac-google-docs-mobile-os-etc/1400484-remove-specific-characters-from-cells-with-appsscript-coding.html)*

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. When I saw your condition, from your sample input and output situations, I cannot understand the logic for obtaining from `[double space] hellOwor2ld` to `hello-world` and from `just?some ! Characters` to `just-some-characters`. Can I ask you about the detailed logic you expect?

Comment: If you want to have the modified string replace the existing string then you need an onEdit trigger or a script.  The following custom formula will produce a string in the format you want `=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(LOWER(B1),"[^a-z\s]",""),"\s","-")` but it would have to be in another cell, say C1 and then the modified string will be in C1.

Comment: Thanks to both for the reply! As you pointed out, I'd like to apply the edits to the original cells, so a script is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my issue:

```
function edit_cells() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let range = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1);
    let values = range.getValues();
    let results = values.map(row => {

      let modifiedString = row[0].toLowerCase();
      modifiedString = modifiedString.replace(/^[\W_]+|[\W_]+$/g, "");
      modifiedString = modifiedString.replace(/\s+/g, "-");
      modifiedString = modifiedString.trim();
      modifiedString = modifiedString.replace(/[\W_]\s+/g, "");
      modifiedString = modifiedString.replace(/(?<=\S)\s+(?=\S)/g, " ");
      return [modifiedString];

    });
    range.setValues(results);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the formula I proposed above I forgot to trim leading and trailing spaces.  It should have been

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(LOWER(TRIM(B1)),"[^a-z\s]",""),"\s","-")
```

Here is a script that will accomplish the same thing for a range of values.  I'm not sure how you want to run it, a menu item, a button, simple from scrpt editor, but I leave that to you to figure out.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let range = sheet.getRange(2,2,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1)
    let values = range.getValues();
    let results = values.map( row => {
        row[0] = row[0].trim().toLowerCase();
        row[0] = row[0].replace(/[^a-z\s]/g,"");
        row[0] = row[0].replace(/\s/g,"-");
        return [row[0]];
      }
    );
    range.setValues(results);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

References:

- [javascript String Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)
- [Array.map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [javascript Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, @TheWizEd! I'll run the script via an onEdit trigger. However, there are still issues in handling some strings. 1) It'd be useful for me to keep the numbers instead of deleting them (I've realized this now, sorry). 2) When I enter "? Apple ?" in a cell, the script gives back "-apple-" instead of "apple". 3) When I enter "somEthing  Written", it prints "something--written" instead of "something-written". Similarly, "just?some ! Characters" becomes "justsome--characters" instead of "justsome-characters". Let me know if this issues could be solved.

Comment: So now you see that your question has grown.  You said only leading and trailing but you mean after any unwanted characters are removed.  And you want multiple spaces replaced with 1 space.  I've given you quite a bit to work with, why don't you try to figure out the rest.